# How do I get back the quantity of products if they haven't been sold?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, datatable, product-quantity

I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I am trying to write a stored procedure where I want to update the quantity of my products and I want to get the specific number of products that has not been confirmed/sold back in stock.

Here is what I got right now:

```
CREATE proc sp_deleteOrders
    (@order_id INT)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS (SELECT status FROM Orders WHERE Orders.Status = 0)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT order_id FROM Orders WHERE Orders.order_id = @order_id)
           DELETE FROM Ordered_Products 
           WHERE Ordered_Products.orderID = @order_id

    DELETE FROM Orders 
    WHERE Orders.order_id = @order_id

    UPDATE Products
    SET product_quantity = product_quantity + Orders.order_quantity
GO
```

The problem is here:

```
SET product_quantity = product_quantity + Orders.order_quantity
```

How do I tell SQL I want the column `order_quantity` from `Orders` and add that to `product_quantity` in `Products`?

Comment: Kindly post the sample data and expected output also so that we can help you better.

Comment: UPDATE table1 
SET table1.name = table2.name + table1.name
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id 
AND table2.foobar ='stuff'
AS @SirchDcmp mentioned please share some sample data for better solution.

Comment: I have a table "Products" where I have a column for quantity. I want that quantity to increase when I delete an order from my "Orders" table. In my Product table I have [product_id]
      ,[product_name]
      ,[product_quantity]
      ,[price] and in my Orders [order_id]
      ,[order_quantity]
      ,[user_id]
      ,[Status]
      ,[order_date]. Hope that this is enough to understand my problem and thank you for reaching out.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra thank you for your help, it worked. Thank you so so much. Have a great day!!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell SQL I want the column order_quantity from Orders and add that to product_quantity in Products?

The answer to your specific question is to use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Products p
    SET product_quantity = p.product_quantity + op.order_quantity
    FROM Products p JOIN
         Ordered_Products op
         ON p.product_id = op.product_id
    WHERE op.order_id = @order_id;
```

Note:  this makes the very reasonable assumption that the quantity is actually in the `Ordered_Products` table.

Also, this won't work with your current structure, because you have deleted the rows before the code attempts the update.  Your code might have other bugs as well; this addresses only the specific question you asked.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this helped a lot. Have an amazing day!!